# Rails how to structure data for Google Charts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-visualization

I want to use google charts to create a graph which looks like:

```
GoogleChart.pie_400x200('Taco Bell'=>0,'Mediterranean'=>2,'Shivas'=>5)
```

Given an object say Results(name, count). How can I create an object for GoogleCharts's structure as seen above?

Thanks

Comment: Right now I can make the results like this in Rails: [{:title=>"Taco Bell", :percentage=>0.0}, {:title=>"The Meditrainian Place", :percentage=>0.0}, {:title=>"Shiva's", :percentage=>100.0}]

Comment: what gem are you using? I am trying to implement Googlecharts in my app but no success..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with the Results object you listed in your comment as `@results`, the following ought to work:

```
GoogleChart.pie_400x200(@results.map {|r| { r[:title] => r[:percentage] } })
```

Comment: Thanks, but that errors with: : syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting '}'